# React Native: How to always route socket packets through WiFi even if it does not have an internet connection?

Tags: android, ios, sockets, react-native

I have a React Native application that uses `TCP` and `UDP` sockets by [bridging](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1ismnuczVAhUIuo8KHWCQAawQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.github.io%2Freact-native%2Fdocs%2Fnative-modules-ios.html&usg=AFQjCNFxseY-wpw3unsP42zuljMZCdSqEw) to Java and Objective-C code. Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to share the code.

The problem is that when I attempt to use these TCP/UDP modules when my phone is on a WiFi network that **does not** have an internet connection they do not work because the packets are being routed through mobile data. If I use my code when on a WiFi that **does** have an internet connection *or* when my mobile data is switched off, it works perfectly. This is true for both platforms Android/iOS.

How can I force all packets to go through the WiFi connection even if it does not have an internet connection?

Thanks.